# "De l'eau de mer a été utilisée pour" -- why do we need "de" before "l'eau de mer"?

Tags: grammaire, partitif

This is from a podcast that was recorded in 2011:

> L'eau de mer autour de la centrale nucléaire de Fukushima a atteint un niveau de radiation dangereusement élevé. En début de la semaine, l'agence japonaise de sûreté nucléaire a affirmé que les nouveaux relevés effectués à 300 m au large des côtes ont montré un niveau d'iode radioactive de 3355 fois la limite légale. **De** l'eau de mer a été utilisée pour empêcher la fusion des réacteurs.

Why do we need that **de** in front of **l'eau de mer** there at the beginning of the sentence? Is its being there really necessary? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do native speakers of French generally use "du/de la" when thinking of nouns like eau, sel, etc?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28256/do-native-speakers-of-french-generally-use-du-de-la-when-thinking-of-nouns-lik) and [Does “je bois du café” make correct use of partitives?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/7165/358)

Comment: Not a exactly a duplicate.  The first links are about *de la* vs zero article and the second one is about *de* vs *de la*. This question is about *de la* vs *la*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*De* is used because sea water hasn't been previously mentioned. The definite article would imply the sea water is one of several known things.

Here is a case where *l'eau* alone could have been used:

> Il y avait de l'eau de mer et du sable. L'eau de mer a été utilisée pour empêcher la fusion des réacteurs.

The indefinite article can't be used (*une eau de mer a été utilisée...*) because there is just one kind of sea water around Fukushima and it is uncountable. You can say *un vin*, *une bière* but not *une eau de mer*.

*De l'eau de mer* means "some unspecified amount of sea water". Unless in English, we can't use "sea water" alone, i.e. *eau de mer* without article, to mean it.

Answer (score 3):

Because water is a [mass noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun) and in French mass nouns normally (there's some edge cases) use the [partitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitive_article) instead of the indefinite article, and the contracted forms don't occur when the regular part of the article is elided, so... *de l'* (as opposed to *du*).